# Django Postgresql Search Not Showing Results

Tags: python, django, full-text-search, django-postgresql, django-searchvector

I'm making a Django website that has **Full Text Search** with Postgres. However, when I make my search, none of the results show up. Is there anything I did wrong? Here's my code:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery, SearchRank
from django.views.generic import ListView, FormView
from .models import Post
from .forms import *

# Create your views here.

class HomepageView(FormView):
    template_name = 'selling/home.html'
    form_class = SearchForm

class Search(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'selling/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        posts = Post.objects.annotate(
            search=SearchVector('title', 'description'),
        ).filter(search=SearchQuery(query))
        return posts
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_contact = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=50)
```

Search.html

```
{% extends "selling/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="ui divided items">
        {% for item in posts %}
        <div class="item">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="{% static 'selling/images/brebeuf.png' %}">
            </div>
            <div class="content item-container">
                <a class="header item-title">{{ item.title }} </a><b class="item-price-right">${{ item.price }}</b>
                <div class="meta">
                    <span>{{ item.postal_code }} &emsp; | &emsp; {{ item.date_posted|date:"d/m/Y" }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="description item-description">
                    <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

home.html

```
{% extends "selling/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method='get'>
  {{ form }}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

settings.py - installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'selling.apps.SellingConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Search, HomepageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomepageView.as_view(), name='sell-home'),
    path('search/', Search.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

That's all the code. Feel free to ask if you need anything else.

Comment: Maybe (not sure) but this line {% for item in posts %} should be {% for item in object_list %}

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much!